# Function doesn't return array

Tags: vba, excel, function

I'm using the function below to find 6 digit numbers in a string. I need to return an array with all 6 digit values, however I keep getting an empty array or empty value whenever I use the function. When I debug the code everything seems fine (the array contains the values I want it to), but after it exits the function the values seem to have disappeared. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
Public Function GetMy6Digits(cell As Range)
Dim s As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim answer
Dim counter As Integer

Dim arrList As Object
Set arrList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") 'Create the ArrayList

'get cell value
s = cell.Value

'set the counter
counter = 0
'loop through the entire string
For i = 1 To Len(s)
    'check to see if the character is a numeric one
    If IsNumeric(Mid(s, i, 1)) = True Then
        'add it to the answer
        answer = answer + Mid(s, i, 1)
        counter = counter + 1
        'check to see if we have reached 8 digits
        If counter = 6 Then
            Item = answer
            arrList.Add (Item)
            counter = 0
'           Exit Function
        End If
     Else
     'was not numeric so reset counter and answer
     counter = 0
     answer = ""
    End If
Next i

Dim arr() As String
ReDim arr(arrList.Count)

For i = 1 To arrList.Count
    arr(i) = arrList(i - 1)
Next i
GetMy6Digits = arr()

End Function
```

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: arr = GetMy6Digits(Worksheet.Range("A" & i))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function returns a 0 based array but you are starting your assignments at 1.

```
For i = 1 To arrList.Count
    arr(i) = arrList(i - 1)
Next i
```

### Correction

```
    For i = 0 To arrList.Count - 1
        arr(i) = arrList(i)
    Next i
```

---